# wire dispensers

Tags: electrical

I was at Menards and I came across this wire dispenser. Looks like it would save a lot of time and hassle. Was wondering if anyone else had some experience with them?[image: Dispenser]

Comment: Use a similar type for heavy electric fence wire, but that is for 100s/1000s of feet.  For one house, usefulness per cost might be limited, many houses/large buildings, could see it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have wire on a spool, it's a simple matter just to get a dowel, small pipe, or chunk of small conduit and support it between a couple of ladders or saw horses (secured of course), but for coils of wire rather than spools, yeah, these are pretty handy. When I wire, I always want them to lay flat, and unwinding a coil to accomplish that is more work. An electrician once showed me how to make something that assisted with pulling cable from a coil, but I forget how he did it.

If the tool you showed isn't too expensive and you have a lot of wiring to do, why not buy it?

EDIT:  Just noticed the price, but ....:"    With the price of 12/2 at about $150 for a 250' coil it seems like money well spent to make your life easier, I'm at the point in my life where I'm writing more checks and doing less work to save time.

Answer (score 2):

These are great. There are several different styles of these which I use for coils of 12 or 14 gauge wire. Some are made to hang on a wood stud or they sit on the floor like the one you have shown.

I would not wire without them. They wire comes off them without all the coils that need to be "unwound" and straightened. The wire will lay flatter. Also the wire will pull out as you need it for your run- you won't have to walk out the length of your run first and then uncoil it before you start your run.,

Comment: Exactly!   Too many times I've walked the coil unwinding on the floor so it wouldn't be twisted, takes a lot more time.   Great minds think alike!